# Trigger with case in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, case

I've got a problem with creating trigger in oracle, I have a table "Tickets" where I have fields "Price" and "Type". I'd like to make a trigger which adds price depending on the type of ticket (normal/reduced).

I'm using `CASE` but it doesn't work at all. Here's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TYPE_BIR
BEFORE INSERT ON Tickets
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    CASE
      WHEN type = "normal" THEN :new.price := "15"
      WHEN type = "reduced" THEN :new.price := "12"
END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "it doesn't work" do you mean it doesn't compile or do you mean it doesn't do what you want it to do?

Try

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TYPE_BIR
BEFORE INSERT ON Tickets
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    IF :new.type = 'normal' THEN 
      :new.price := 15 ;
    ELSIF :new.type = 'reduced' THEN 
      :new.price := 12 ;
    END IF ;
END;
```

I've assumed price is NUMBER

Or if you want to use CASE...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TYPE_BIR
BEFORE INSERT ON Tickets
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    CASE :new.type
      WHEN 'normal' THEN :new.price := 15 ;
      WHEN 'reduced' THEN :new.price := 12 ;
    END CASE ;
END;
```

Comment: It WORKS! Thanks a lot!

Comment: try again but use single quotes (') not double quotes (")